# Dynamic link creation for each list item

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list, hyperlink, list-item

I want to get the ID of a list item each time an item created.

I have a list with couple of columns, one of columns is type `Image`. I want to have a list view which will show only the column `Image`, but when user clicks on the image he/she should get a pop up display form.

So, I want to know if it is possible to get the ID of the created item?

Basically I need to get item ID for this link:

```
https://link/sites/sitename/Lists/listname/DispForm.aspx?ID=<numberofitem>
```

Afterwards I know how and what to do.

**Environment**

- SharePoint 2013
- SharePoint Designer (I can only use SPD as a tool. I am not allowed to use Visual Studio.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `calculated column` and `concat` "https://link/sites/sitename/Lists/listname/DispForm.aspx?ID=" and item id. This will suffice your requirement. Also if you want to display column value as a link, check out this [link](https://devdotnotes.wordpress.com/2012/01/29/sharepoint-caculated-column-and-hyperlink-no-workflow-or-script-needed/).

If `workflow` is an option, you can start a workflow on item created and set a hyperlink column with item's display form URL. Check the screenshow below:
[image]

Update list item:

[image]

Comment: I know all of this, but how to get item ID automatically?

Comment: can you use workflow?

Comment: Yes. I can use it.

Comment: Then write a workflow which will update a hyperlink column. you can always find a current item ID in workflow. I'll update my answer

Comment: I see now. I totally forgot I can pull item ID in workflow. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest using current Item URL though!

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add for anyone still looking for this:

Using ID in a calculated column will not work once a new item is created or a current one is edited - The Workflow option is the best/ only option.